# Calculate Average of 5 Integers Using an Array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I can't seem to get it right. The question is "Calculate the Average of 5 Integers using an array"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int avg[5],i,total;
    int average;

    printf("Enter the marks entered in 5 subjects");
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i){
        scanf("%d",&avg[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<5; ++i){
        total = total + avg[i];
    }

    average= (float)total/5;
    printf("The average of 5 marks is %d",average);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What's going wrong here?  What value are you getting compared to your expected result?  Try setting `total` to 0 before you start adding to it.

Comment: "*`average= (float)total/5;`*": Why casting to `float` when assiging the result to an `int` again?

Comment: Your question actually misses the question.

Comment: Accept an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

1) Your answer CAN be a decimal number but you are storing it in an integer which ignores the decimal points. 
The variable `average` should be declared as `float average;`
The line where you print the result should be changed to `printf("The average of 5 marks is %f",average);`

2) Initialize the variable `total` as `int total = 0;`

Answer (score 3):

`total` should be initialized to `0`:

```
int avg[5],i,total=0;
```

Answer (score 3):

In the for loop's first iteration, variable `total` is used uninitialized, so the result is wrong since it will automatically acquire a garbage value if not initialized explicitly. Take this whole thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int avg[5], i, total = 0, average;
    printf("Enter the marks entered in 5 subjects");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &avg[i]);
        total += avg[i];
    }
    average = total / 5;
    printf("The average of 5 marks is %d", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've just declared the variable total but didn't initialize it. So, total contains a garbage value. For that if you add anything to total, the value will not be the correct as expected. It will be added to the garbage value. So,initialize the variable total with 0.

```
int total=0;
```

You need not to use type casting. Just declare the average variable as double.

```
double average=0;
average = total/5.0;
```

And you should print as `printf("The average of 5 marks is %lf", average);`

Comment: `total` does *not* contain "nothing". Some programming languages allow 'nothing' (not even `0`, which is 'something' - a number) but C does not. It contains a value but it is not initialized, and so the value *can be* anything. Even `0` (but you should not count on that).

Comment: Yes..Actually I meant it contains Garbage value. I also edited my answer. Hope it is okay now. 
Thank you.

Comment: The `l` in `%lf` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

`total` is a local variable, hence it needs to be initialised. Had it been within file scope (like, a global variable), or a static variable, you might not have to initialise it to `0`.

An initialisation could be simply like:

```
int avg[5], i, total = 0 ;
```

or

```
int avg[5], i, total;
total = 0 ;
```

Why do you need initialisation? Because of this statement:

```
 total = total + avg[i];
```

Here `total` is calculated using its previous value. What is `total`'s previous value the first time this statement is encountered? It could be anything, commonly referred to as garbage value, invoking undefined behaviour. Hence, you need initialisation to give this starting value to `total`. Note, you don't *need* to initialise `average`, because its value does not depend on its previous contents.

---

Another problem is with the concepts of `typecasting`. Here is the statement:

```
average= (float)total/5;
```

You are right about typecasting `total` to `float` (you may also have done `total/5.0` instead). However, you are storing the result in an `integer`. This will result in a *second* typecasting, from the result in `float` to `int`.

Hence, you need to declare `average` as a `float`.

(**Note**: If having a `float` result is not your requirement, and you really need an `integral` answer, you may ignore this part).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize variables before you use them in your code.

What goes WRONG in your code is,

```
int avg[5],i,total;
```

where you have not initialized the int variable "total"
Hence this code will use a garbage value

```
for(i=0; i<5; ++i){
    total = total + avg[i];
}
```

You need this correction

```
int avg[5], i, total=0;
```